# Confused about FLD m64fp instruction

Tags: assembly, fpu

So I have multiple questions about FLD m64fp instructions, one example is this:

Eight consecutive bytes in memory contain the hex values 01, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00. An FLD m64fp instruction is executed. Its argument is the address of the first of these eight consecutive bytes. As a result of the FLD instruction, the value in ST(0) is now:

1. 2^-1075
2. 2^-1074
3. 2^-1023
4. 2^-1022

This IS a homework question so I'm not asking for the answer, but I am confused about what's going on. I've spent the last few days reading about the FPU register but I haven't found much that makes this question understandable. Are all eight of those values initially loaded into the register? If so what happens when FLD is called when the register is already full? I'm pretty confused. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m64fp` stands for a 64-bit-memory-address. The assembler should be smart enough to choose the right `FLD` instruction if the variable is appropriate declared (DQ, REAL8 or similar). 64 bit are 8 bytes, so FLD loads 8 bytes (keyword: little endian) at once.

The value will be "pushed onto the FPU stack", i.e. ST(6) becomes ST(7), ST(5) becomes ST(6), ST(4) becomes ST(5) ... ST(0) becomes ST(1) and ST(0) becomes the value from `FLD`. If the stack is full `FLD` fails, but this is presumably not part of your homework.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints as to what you can look at:

- x86 endianness.
- How the 8087 stack is organized and how the instructions FLD and FILD affect it.
- How memory, accessed by the two instruction types, is interpreted.

Wikipedia has articles on the 8087/x87 and the ieee754 standards you might want to look at.